# CSR "поверх" SSR - имеет ли смысл?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, seo, nuxt.js, ssr

**Является ли нормальной практикой следующий подход:**

1. Отдать клиенту страницу, используя SSR *(Server Side Rendering)* (клиент получает html-документ с разметкой, готовой к отрисовке в браузере)
2. Заменить контент (или часть контента) на странице, используя CSR *(Client Side Rendering)*

**Менее абстрактный пример:**

Рендерим страницу из Django-шаблона, на страницу подключаем JS-скрипт *(для ещё меньшей абстракции пускай это будет Vue.JS)*. После получения страницы клиентом, скрипт инициализируется, происходит монтирование компонента в один из DOM-элементов - то есть происходит клиентский рендеринг, который перезаписывает собой то, что отдал сервер

Насколько мне известно, SSR на стороне фреймворка (например Nuxt.Js) работает примерно таким же образом, с оговоркой в том, что SSR-контент не полностью перезаписывается CSR-контентом, а "гидратируется" - добавляются только новые элементы/собтия/етц

**Причины использования такого механизма, которые я вижу:**

- Страница отданная SSR-ом более SEO-дружелюбна (как минимум есть гарантии того, что поисковые роботы её прочитают)
- Интерактивные элементы проще реализовывать, используя какой-либо фреймворк *(конкретно в этом вопросе он **нужен**)*

Жизнеспособна ли такая схема в принципе (будет ли выигрыш, во времени FCP *(First Contentful Paint)* и SEO)? Или можно отказаться от этапа SSR и отдавать клиенту пустой документ со скриптом, отрисовывающим контент?

Comment: добавь расшифровку аббревиатурам

Comment: Вообще не понял, как всё перечисленное связано.

Comment: @Qwertiy связано всё тем, что необходима хорошая SEO и использование Vue. Где-то посередине между SEO и Vue стоит упомянутый Nuxt, который использовать не могу.
Главный вопрос, на который хочется узнать ответ - "Делается ли так вообще? (Когда отдается страничка от SSR, а поверх неё рендерится что-то на JS)"

Comment: О, расшифровка аббревиатур помога - я думал, там про сертификат. Современные фреймвёрки все умеют серверный рендеринг и потом продолжить работать на странице (у реакта это называется гидрацией, у вью - не знаю). В чём проблема - не понял. Или ты хочешь, чтобы скрипт что-то менял сам без действий пользователя и страница со скриптами и без получалась разной?

Comment: Нет, суть в том, что SSR в моем случае происходит вообще не в JS и никакого отношения к нему не имеет (этим Джанго занимается), поэтому гидратацию если и можно сделать, то, скорее всего, только вручную (если это не так, прошу поправить)
Проблемы, как таковой нет, интересна теоретическая сторона вопроса - принято ли вообще так делать? Нигде не видел такого подхода и, можно сказать, придумал его на ходу, поэтому интересны подводные камни, которые мог не учесть

Comment: Как оказалось, гидрация в Vue поддерживается из коробки: https://v2.ssr.vuejs.org/guide/hydration.html
Не додумался сразу проверить этот момент, все оказалось куда проще :)